# Не помещается результат при выводе

Tags: python, numpy

Используя numpy, работаю с матрицами. Нужно вывести матрицу очень больших размеров (801*801). При выводе матрица обрезается и я вижу лишь несколько элементов.

Как все же вывести полную матрицу? 
Либо записать ее в текстовый файл, но нужна именно полная матрица.

Comment: np.savetxt(filename, array_name) - в файле будет необрезанная матрица

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте такой пример

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.zeros((801, 801), np.int8)
>>> np.savetxt('arr.out', arr)
```

должен помочь.